# finding database Path

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to find the physical path of SQL Server file (.mdf)?
I have VS2010 where I browse the SQL Server database in Server Explorer window.
I do not have sql Server Management studio.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you need that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the database where name = 'master'.  Just change this to the database you're looking for.

```
SELECT name, physical_name AS current_file_location
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE name = 'master'
```

You can also try:

```
SELECT filename FROM sys.sysfiles
```

This gives the default locations

```
 DECLARE @defaultDataLocation nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @defaultLogLocation nvarchar(4000)

EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread
    N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',
    N'DefaultData', 
    @defaultDataLocation OUTPUT

EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread
    N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',
    N'DefaultLog', 
    @defaultLogLocation OUTPUT

SELECT @defaultDataLocation,    @defaultLogLocation
```

Comment: if you are in the database try: SELECT * FROM sysfiles

Comment: The second part of the accepted answer (registry read) worked for me to give the DEFAULT location of user databases - this is exactly what I was looking for! Excellent, thank you!